# How can I feed a file into a program that reads stdin (on Windows command line)?

Tags: command-line

I have a **program P** that processes stdin. How can I feed a **file** into this program from the **Windows command line**?

```
P < filename
```

does not work.

```
filename | P
filename > P
```

does not work either.

**edit**

tried again, in fact

```
P < filename
```

or

```
grep abc < lab.txt
```

**does work**.

Comment: What OS are you working on?

Comment: Command redirection in MS Windows works just like in GNU/Linux. If `p < myfile` is not working, it probably is not a problem of the redirection. Try something like `sort < myfile` and see what happens.

Comment: as mentioned, p < file does not work.

Comment: i can certainly write a program that reads the file and forwards it to stdout. i just wonder if such thing does exist already.

Comment: which language are you using to make this *program P* ?

Comment: P is written in C#, .Net .

Comment: Try to post your program in StackOverflow, I think it might be a problem in the program. Or maybe you forgot to specify the output:
**P.exe <input_filename.txt >output_filename.txt** (note that even if the filenames are hidden you still must use them for passing the names)

Comment: my program is correct, please do not doubt that. the behavior is the same when I exchange P with grep for instance.

Comment: Have you tried **`type filename | P`**

Comment: that works also, interesting, thx!

Comment: Does that solve your problem? Should I post that as an answer? ... Wait, I see you edited your question that **`P < filename `** is now working. Sounds like you no longer have a problem.

Comment: yes, feel free to do so, your solution is correct. actually the hints from bjanssen was also correct, since P < file in fact works.

Comment: Beware, using `type` seems to sometimes "eat" newlines in the input (if the newline is on an internal buffer boundary, I suspect -- rather nasty to get `42` where `4\n2` is in the file); the approach with `<` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991395/110118) seems to work nice though

Answer (score 2):

I tried this script that set the contents of the filename as variable "a" and then fed this variable "a" as an argument to the "p" program.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims={" %%a in ('TYPE filename ^| FINDstr /r "[a-z]"') do (cmd /c p "%%a")
pause
```

Note that this script has a number of limitations as I used regular expression in findstr command supposing that the contents of filename is just text.
I don't know what your filename contents are so you have to modify it to suites your needs.
Also you need to modify your program "p" so that it accepts arguments.
Hope this help.